# Node.js Firestore SDK Error on Persistence Offline

Tags: firebase, vue.js, electron, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem to enable Firebase/Firestore Offline Persistence with Electron and Vue.js.

This is my code: firebaseInit.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

var db = firebase.firestore()

const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true}
db.settings(settings)

db.enablePersistence()
  .then(function () {
    // Initialize Cloud Firestore through firebase
    // var db = firebase.firestore()
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    if (err.code === 'failed-precondition') {
      // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
      // in one tab at a a time.
      // ...
    } else if (err.code === 'unimplemented') {
      // The current browser does not support all of the
      // features required to enable persistence
      // ...
    }
  })

export default db
```

This code return an error on console:

[image]